# how to get all first items of sublists in python

Tags: python

I feel really stupid asking for that, but i'm having issues using my list, i'm surely doing something wrong but here is the code :

```
myList = ['21 25 5', '16 20 18', '16 20 16', '2 3 2', '2 3 1']

lst2 = [item[0] for item in myList]
print(lst2)

output : ['2', '1', '1', '2', '2']
```

I am trying the access the first values of each item and i want the output to be like this :

```
['21', '16', '16', '2', '2']
```

thanks for your help !

Comment: So, your `myList` *does* have sublists, except they are strings and the first element of a string is the first character.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [str.split](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to split each item by whitespaces:

```
myList = ['21 25 5', '16 20 18', '16 20 16', '2 3 2', '2 3 1']

lst2 = [item.split()[0] for item in myList]

print(lst2)
```

**Output**

```
['21', '16', '16', '2', '2']
```

Your code is accessing the first element of each string.

As an alternative as you are only interested in the first element use `maxsplit` argument:

```
lst2 = [item.split(maxsplit=1)[0] for item in myList]
```

From the documentation:

> If maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit splits are done (thus, the list
> will have at most maxsplit+1 elements)